parallelization for large matrix multiplication
I have two, rather large, torch-matrices :
A : ( 3 000 000, 20 ) and B : ( 20, 15 000 ) and I need to multiply them A * B, and then process each column i of the resulting matrix with a function f( ( A*B )[i,:] ).
In the beginning I tried to multiply the matrices using torch-operator, but got an out of memory error, then I did a simple for- loop to compute individually each ( A*B )[:, i] and compute the f() of such interim result in the said for-loop, but it was very long.
Obviously, whichever way I compute the matrix multiplication, the result does not fit in the memory of my machine.
I am trying to find a trade off between memory and time consumption so I wrote a piece of code that process the multiplication by a batch of column-segments i:j ~ ( A*B )[:,i:j] and process this segment-result in f(), using a for-loop.
My questions are the following :

When I write the following code :

y = []
for i in range(10):
   x = A * B[:, batch_size * i : batch_size * (i + 1) ]
   y.append(f(x))

is the memory used for x released every time ? How can I manually make sure that at each iteration the memory has been released ?

Should I multiprocess the for loop ? : my point is that when I perform A * B[:, batch_size * i : batch_size * (i + 1) ] op, it is a torch-op, which already uses multiprocessing, so if I try to multiprocess the for-loop, am I not going to have a loss of time on the torch matrix multiplication time ?

I tried the full mat mul, then the for loop then the batch mat mul

The memory for x is, indeed released (well, it will eventually be), so that it won't cause a memory error. I think multiprocessing won't bring you anything (the * op should already be highly optimized, so trying to do its job yourself won't likely be of any use).

it's not released until the end of the scope, but it is overwritten in the next iteration of the for loop. You can manually release it using del x


Q1 :"/__part_A__/ When I write the following code (...)/__part_B__/ is the memory used for x released every time ? /__part_C__/ How can I manually make sure that at each iteration the memory has been released ?"

Part A :

"When I write the following code(...)"

the Python Interpreter actually "sees" this sequence of then interpreted pseudo-instructions :
>>> dis.dis( demo_as_was )
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              83 (to 86)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                69 (to 85)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)

  3          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (A)
             22 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (B)
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             31 BUILD_SLICE              2
             34 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (batch_size)
             37 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             40 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             41 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (batch_size)
             44 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             47 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             50 BINARY_ADD          
             51 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             52 BUILD_SLICE              2
             55 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             58 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             59 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             60 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  4          63 LOAD_GLOBAL              4 (y)
             66 LOAD_ATTR                5 (append)
             69 LOAD_GLOBAL              6 (f)
             72 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             75 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             78 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             81 POP_TOP             
             82 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   85 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   86 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             89 RETURN_VALUE        

all this will make sense if and only if the f( arg )-function has a property of being additive over its arguments arg, i.e. that you can provethat f( A ) = ( f( B ) + f( C ) ) for every such A, B and C, that meet condition A = B + C,otherwisethis is the showstopper & we can enjoy just another cup of tea and watch meteorites on the sky.
Assuming ( not having such proof explicitly claimed in the O/P that holds ), we can proceed:
In Python interpreted language engine, your educators should have told you, the symbols, like the x, are not the same as compiler-time decided, linker-executed, hard-wired strategy of placing the actual run-time data ( where & how ), that the compiled code will ( more or less, depending on language brutality ) reference just by (almost) blind "pointing"-towards such ( pre-determined, in method ) memory location. Collisions ( of taking/putting wrong data or doing so in an "unsafe" or even straight "wrong" moment(s) ) and Segmentation faults crashes can fill its own Hall of Fame.
Not in Python - Python symbol ( the x ) is a "named"-reference ( hard-working Python developers could nail me here on not being as exact as ought be, when describing the internal beauties of how the Python Interpreter architecture works, yet a global view idea is for us at this moment quite okay and I can take any improvements proposed here, to hit the nail better ).
A "named"-reference is associated with some value, the same x in Python Interpreter can associate with an interim product of A*B while a next moment it can "be made" to associate with anything else, like after a SLOC "saying" Python Interpreter to "do" x = "Not to get confused here."
The "previous" association was "cut" ( the referred matrix-object was left "not associated (also) with" the said x from this moment on ) and the "new" association leads Python Interpreter to follow the new said rule "If anybody says here ( i.e. inside this inner scope-of-visibility ) to use x, go and take the "Not to get confused here."-string-alike object ... "
As we now better distinguish the symbol from its (current) content, we can better feel a difference between a del x ( a SLOC to delete a symbol ), saying Python Interpreter not much more than just "forget to go anywhere for anything, if anyone since now says to touch x ( as now there is none such symbol, named x, known about ) and rather throw Undefined Exception",whilea completely different story is the Part B and Part C i.e. the way, how Python Interpreter actually gets rid of ( if it was permitted to do so ) the potentially huge areas of memory-storage resources, where the last-, potentially also the previous- and similarly all pre-previous- associated data was actually stored ( and potentially not associated with any other Python Interpreter symbol, so being free to get freed ... if ... ).
Here the darkest moments come. Both in SPACE-related and TIME-related impacts any "cleanup" processing might and will, if permitted and ordered to be done, will have on the normal work of the Python Interpreter as you know it.
When designing for low-latency, high-performance, this is our nightmare.
A built-in garbage-collection tool exists, yet it takes time ( during which your code will stop and wait ) -- which is a straight anti-pattern to what you expressed you want to solve ( in minimum TIME and restricted SPACE ).
Placing anything near to this inside a loop, that will be run about 1E+9 times is simply not the way to go.

Q2 :" Should I multiprocess the for loop ? "

This is simple. No. Never here. Not in your context.
Given a SPACE-constraint ( RAM ) was declared to block the most straightforward way of computing ( so resorting to, assumed only so far, segmented processing, if mathematical properties of function f() permit ), the first thing one shall notice in using Python Interpreter multiprocessing-module ( for the sake of spawned-processes escape from central Python Interpreter GIL-lock, as it works since ever and almost forever ( attempts, going against Guido's original guesstimate the GIL-lock will never change, as it is the iron-warranty for non-colliding ( as GIL-lock serves as a concurrency-avoider ) and simplicity of the internal design of the Python Interpreter engine, are trying to re-design the interpreter to become GIL-free, yet none such project has landed so far to be proven as both correct ( working as safe as GIL-lock orchestrated Python ) and at least as fast as the original, GIL-lock protected code - so even this is a direction not to go into, at least not in 2024-Q3 ).
Safe multiprocessing works ( as declared so far, in 2024-Q3 ) using fully spawned processes ( read as a one-stop add-on overhead in TIME- + SPACE-domains ),next comes a full-copy of the Python Interpreter internal state ( read as an immense SPACE-domain cost to replicate as many copies of the original memory-footprint of the calling Python Interpreter including all its internal state ... yes ... The DATA ... which almost did not fit into your so far available RAM ... oops, that hurts to realize this drawback as late as here, if not have been told earlier ) and last, but not least, even if all this fit into RAM, the actual processing will suffocate the physical CPU-mem_IO_controller-phys_RAM dataflows ( if not carefully curated for an in-cache-only computing with a bit reduced phys_RAM read-s, where possible, to leave more time for write-through dataflows back to phys_RAM ).
Well,this is how the current toys actually do work, no matter what kinds of syntax sugar were used around the bare-metal nature of the things, as we stand in 2024-Aug ... and most of our toys will remain doing so or almost the same for quite remarkably long time in the near future, so better follow the way, how the toys actually work as any attempt to go otherwise will cost you, if nothing else, for sure more TIME ( in processing ) and wasted efforts ( in colliding & refactoring the code ).
Life is so exciting, isn't it - keep it full of joy of inventions, building understanding & insights into the beauties of how the world actually works, boring things or bad ideas do not deserve our time &  resources nor our attention, do they?
